# Excel VBA renames the wrong sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an excel macro-enabled workbook that has 5 sheets. One of these sheets is named "NC" and one is named "SC". I have part of the code which adds dates to these sheets' names.

Sheets("NC").Name = "NC" & Replace(Date, "/", "-")
Sheets("SC").Name = "SC" & Replace(Date, "/", "-")

Then later on if the reset button is clicked, I made a code to switch them back to previous "NC" and "SC" names but this is where I get the problem.

Sheets(2).Name = "NC"
Sheets(3).Name = "SC"

Sheets(2).Name = "NC" works fine
Sheets(3).Name = "SC" however, renames Sheet(4) instead

I thought these sheet codes or sheet numbers don't change no matter how you rearrange or reorder your sheet tabs. I don't understand why it accurately renamed Sheets(2) but not Sheets(3). Look at my project explorer below, it renames Sheets(4) instead from "NCToday" to "SC". Sheets(3) is showing "SC" in the picture but because this was manually reset but you can see the arrangement, the code Sheets(3).Name = "SC" SHOULD NOT have renamed Sheets(4) from "NCToday" to "SC".

[image: Sheet List]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheet(3) does not necessarily mean sheet3

Example:
[image]

If I type into the immediate window, `?worksheets(1).name`, I get this result:

> Sheet2

note that the system looks at the sheet order on the excel spreadsheet (Sheet2,Sheet1, Sheet3), not the order in the VBA Project (Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3)

To rename the sheets back, you may want to reverse the method you used to rename them initially:

```
Sheets("SC" & Replace(Date, "/", "-")).Name = "SC"
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks so much for the quick response. I did some testing before I saw your answer and found out using msgbox, it follows the sheet order. I was confused a bit still but I came back here to update, saw your response, everything's now as clear as a clean water :) I couldn't use your suggestion though, if they try to reset the sheet names the next day (Different date) then that would be a problem. I just placed a Notification "Please do not rearrange the sheets".:)

Comment: Will Worksheets(1).name give me "Sheet1" though even if the tab for Sheet1 is placed after Sheet3? I'm thinking using Worksheets(1) will give me what I wanted instead of Sheets(1)?

Comment: worksheets(1) will give you the first sheet in the order displayed on the excel workbook. if you use `Sheet1.` it will use the **sheet1** displayed in the project file, regardless of what it's name is

Comment: Ok Thanks, each sheets have different columns and My code includes looping statements like Sheets(SheetIndex).value and during the process, the code renames these sheets, so it's very complicated for me. I'll just hope no-one rearranges the sheet tabs or else it's gonna ruin their day :p

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to refer to a worksheet.

Using

```
Sheets(number).Name 

'this will print all the names in the Sheets(i) order
for i = 1 to Sheets.count
    debug.pring sheets(i).name & " at index " & i
next i
```

renames the sheet at index `number` in the workbook from left to right.

Using

```
Sheet2.name = "NC"
```

will rename the VBA object `Sheet2` shown in the explorer.

I suspect you want to do:

```
Sheet2.Name = "NC" 
Sheet3.Name = "SC"
```

Comment: Thanks enderland, I actually found out what went wrong, when you rearrange the sheets' tabs it also changes their sheet code/number.

Comment: @Jay note that the `Sheet2.Name` will work *regardless* of sheet order.

Comment: So that's what I'm looking for then :) But how can I loop that? I mean what if I need to rename Sheet1.Name, Sheet2.Name, and Sheet3.Name or do additional codes for each, is there a way to loop it or do I have to do it without looping?

Comment: @Jay I do not think so, because you are referencing the specific object for each sheet.

Comment: you can loop though the sheets and check the codename or if you have programmatic access to the vb project trusted you can use `Sheets(CStr(activeWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet" & n).Properties("Name")))` for instance

Comment: Ok Thanks, each sheets have different columns and My code includes looping statements like Sheets(SheetIndex).value and during the process, the code renames these sheets, so it's very complicated for me. I'll just hope no-one rearranges the sheet tabs or else it's gonna ruin their day :p

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use the Like option to compare the sheet names before renaming ?

```
Dim s as Worksheet
For each s in Worksheets

    if s.Name like "NC*" and not s.Name = "NCToday" then
         s.Name = "NC"
    end if

next
```

That could solve your page-shuffle without having to resort to "Do Not Re-Shuffle comments" ?

Comments like that are prone to misinterpretation and will likely have your code run into troubles and errors at some stage.

Better to try and mae it foolproof !

Goodluck !

Cheers !